# How can one implement a React buildContext function which takes a generic hook as parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

Hello all smart people here at stack overflow.

I would like to write a generic `buildContext` utility function using typescript which takes a hook as parameter and returns an object containing `Provider`, `Consumer`, `useState` and `useActions`, but I fail to see how I can make it support generic hooks.

I've currently got a working `buildContext` utility function supporting hooks which is not generic. It supports taking a hook as parameter and returning an above mentioned object.

Bellow follows the code for implementing this utility function:

```
import * as React from "react";

type Function<S, A, P> = (props: P) => { state: S; actions: A };

export default function buildContext<S, A, P extends object>(
  useHook: Function<S, A, P>
) {
  const StateContext = React.createContext<S | undefined>(undefined);
  const ActionsContext = React.createContext<A | undefined>(undefined);

  const Provider: React.SFC<P> = ({ children, ...props }) => {
    const { state, actions } = useHook(props as P);

    return (
      <StateContext.Provider value={state}>
        <ActionsContext.Provider value={actions}>
          {children}
        </ActionsContext.Provider>
      </StateContext.Provider>
    );
  };

  const useState = () => {
    const context = React.useContext(StateContext);
    if (context === undefined) {
      throw Error("Missing Provider for useState");
    }
    return context;
  };

  const useActions = () => {
    const context = React.useContext(ActionsContext);
    if (context === undefined) {
      throw Error("Missing Provider for useActions");
    }
    return context;
  };

  const StateConsumer: React.SFC<{
    children: ({ state }: { state: S }) => React.ReactNode;
  }> = ({ children }) => {
    return (
      <StateContext.Consumer>
        {state => {
          if (state === undefined) {
            throw Error("Missing Provider for StateConsumer");
          }
          return children({ state });
        }}
      </StateContext.Consumer>
    );
  };
  const ActionsConsumer: React.SFC<{
    children: ({ actions }: { actions: A }) => React.ReactNode;
  }> = ({ children }) => {
    return (
      <ActionsContext.Consumer>
        {actions => {
          if (actions === undefined) {
            throw Error("Missing Provider for ActionsConsumer");
          }
          return children({ actions });
        }}
      </ActionsContext.Consumer>
    );
  };

  return {
    Provider,
    useState,
    useActions,
    StateConsumer,
    ActionsConsumer
  };
}
```

*The utility function can be found here, with a short example:
[github/build-context](https://github.com/FrimJo/build-context)*

I would like to be able to do something similar to this:

```
function useTest<T>(props: { thing: T }) {
  return {
    state: { thing: props.thing },
    actions: {},
  }
}

const Context = buildContext(useTest)

// Thought 1
const Component = (props) => (
  <Context.Provider thing={'ball'}> // 'ball' here could be anything
    <Context.Consumer>
    {props => (
      <div>{props.thing}</div>
    )}
    </Context.Consumer>
  </Context.Provider>
  const { thing } = Context.useState()
)

// Thought 2
const Component = (props) => (
  <Context.Provider<string> thing={'ball'}> // 'ball' here needs to be a string
    <Context.Consumer>
    {props => (
      <div>{props.thing}</div>
    )}
    </Context.Consumer>
  </Context.Provider>
  const { thing } = Context.useState()
)
```

I'm grateful for all the help I can get, cheers!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? The main hanging point that I've found is that createContext would need access to the generic type, and you can only do that by calling a function, which then, in turn, creates a new context... essentially what it comes down to is instantiating a generic type, which is by definition impossible. I'm still searching for a way to do this, but I'm stuck.

Comment: @fullStackChris Sorry to say, I have not.

I actually forgot that I already had asked this question on StackOverflow and have just created a new question with a better explanation of the problem with examples.

See [Typing for a generic context builder taking generic hook as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68687793/typing-for-a-generic-context-builder-taking-generic-hook-as-argument)